# What is $.metadata.setType('attr', 'data'); in jQuery

Tags: jquery

Is there somebody here can explain what is `$.metadata.setType('attr', 'data');` and how it works? I am wondering what is it mean because I haven't used jquery for long. This is my first time.

Thank u very much :-)

Comment: It's not a standard part of jQuery - do you know which plugin is being used? My guess would be that it's an old relic of pre-HTML5 times which allowed metadata to be stored against an element. If so, use the `data()` method instead.

Comment: ah okay. . I checked again the code and you are right, it stored the data inside the element. Thank u

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly then its a part of jQuery.metadata.js and `$.metadata.setType('attr', 'data');` is used for parsing metadata from elements where *u can define the metadata type, use $(expr) to load the metadata into the elements matched by expr, then redefine the metadata type and run another $(expr) for other elements*.